# Pytorch, `backward` RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, backpropagation, reinforcement-learning, loss

I'm implementing DDPG with PyTorch (0.4) and got stuck backproping the loss.
So, first my Code performing the update:

```py
def update_nets(self, transitions):
    """
    Performs one update step
    :param transitions: list of sampled transitions
    """
    # get batches
    batch = transition(*zip(*transitions))
    states = torch.stack(batch.state)
    actions = torch.stack(batch.action)
    next_states = torch.stack(batch.next_state)
    rewards = torch.stack(batch.reward)

    # zero gradients
    self._critic.zero_grad()

    # compute critic's loss
    y = rewards.view(-1, 1) + self._gamma * \
        self.critic_target(next_states, self.actor_target(next_states))

    loss_critic = F.mse_loss(y, self._critic(states, actions),
                             size_average=True)

    # backpropagte it
    loss_critic.backward()
    self._optim_critic.step()

    # zero gradients
    self._actor.zero_grad()

    # compute actor's loss
    loss_actor = ((-1.) * self._critic(states, self._actor(states))).mean()

    # backpropagate it
    loss_actor.backward()
    self._optim_actor.step()

    # do soft updates
    self.perform_soft_update(self.actor_target, self._actor)
    self.perform_soft_update(self.critic_target, self._critic)
```

Where `self._actor`, `self._crtic`, `self.actor_target` and `self.critic_target` are Nets.

If I run this, I get the following error in the second iteration:

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.

at 

line 221, in update_nets
    loss_critic.backward()
line 93, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
line 89, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
```

and I don't know what is causing it.

What I know till now is, that the `loss_critic.backward()` call causes the error.
I already debugged `loss_critic` - it got a valid value.
If I replace the loss computation with a simple

```py
loss_critic = torch.tensor(1., device=self._device, dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True)
```

Tensor containing the value `1` it works fine.
Also, I already checked that I'm not saving some results which could cause the error.
Additionally updating the actor with the `loss_actor` doesn't cause any problems.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Thanks!

**Update**

I replaced

```py
    # zero gradients
    self._critic.zero_grad()
```

and

```py
    # zero gradients
    self._actor.zero_grad()
```

with

```py
    # zero gradients
    self._critic.zero_grad()
    self._actor.zero_grad()
    self.critic_target.zero_grad()
    self.actor_target.zero_grad()
```

(both calls) but it is still failing with the same error.
Additionally, the code performing the update at the end of one iteration

```py
def perform_soft_update(self, target, trained):
    """
    Preforms the soft update
    :param target: Net to be updated
    :param trained: Trained net - used for update
    """
    for param_target, param_trained in \
            zip(target.parameters(), trained.parameters()):
        param_target.data.copy_(
            param_target.data * (
                    1.0 - self._tau) + param_trained * self._tau
        )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytorch - RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274929/pytorch-runtimeerror-trying-to-backward-through-the-graph-a-second-time-but)

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.
I saved tensors in my `replay_buffer`, for training purposes, which I used in every iteration resulting in the code snippet:

```py
    # get batches
    batch = transition(*zip(*transitions))
    states = torch.stack(batch.state)
    actions = torch.stack(batch.action)
    next_states = torch.stack(batch.next_state)
    rewards = torch.stack(batch.reward)
```

This "saving" of tensors is the cause of the problem. So I changed my code to save only the data (`tensor.data.numpy().tolist()`) and only put it into a tensor when I need it.

More detailed:
In DDPG I evaluate the policy every iteration and do one learning step with a batch.
Now I'm saving the evaluation in the replay buffer via:

```py
action = self.action(state)
...
self.replay_buffer.push(state.data.numpy().tolist(), action.data.numpy().tolist(), ...)
```

And used it like:

```py
batch = transition(*zip(*transitions))
states = self.to_tensor(batch.state)
actions = self.to_tensor(batch.action)
next_states = self.to_tensor(batch.next_state)
rewards = self.to_tensor(batch.reward)
```

Comment: Do you know why saving tensors didn't work but saving underlying data worked? Hope to know the answer.

Comment: The reason saving tensors do not work is routed in the autograd-function/prop/... of tensors. I do not know the specifics, but I read that you should always save the data and never the tensor (rule of thumb).. .

Comment: Clarification: Of course you should use tensors to e.g. compute your loss (avoid unnecessary data conversion, especially cpu-gpu ones..). But if you want to save data, in order to use it later, you should save the data you need and not the hole tensor.

Comment: The reason for the error is (I think), that when you call `backwards()` the grad from every tensor is computed. If you've got a saved tensor, which already has a grad saved, the computation will fail (therefore the need to call `.zero_grad()`)...

Answer (score 0):

Didn't call `zero_grad()` on `self.actor_target` and `self.critic_target`? Or is it called in `self.perform_soft_update()`?

Comment: I didn't (because I thought it isn't necessary) so I added it (I'll update the question) but it is still failing with the same error