# Pytorch - inference all images and back-propagate batch by batch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a **special** use case that I have to separate inference and back-propagation: I have to inference **all** images and **slice** outputs into batches followed by back-propagating batches by batches. I **don't** need to update my network's weights.

I modified snippets of [cifar10_tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html) into the following to simulate my problem: `j` is a variable to represent the index which returns by my own logic and I want the gradient of some variables.

```py
for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs
        inputs, labels = data
        inputs.requires_grad = True

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)

        for j in range(4): # j is given by external logic in my own case

            loss = criterion(outputs[j, :].unsqueeze(0), labels[j].unsqueeze(0))

            loss.backward()

            print(inputs.grad.data[j, :]) # what I really want
```

I got the following errors:

> RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.

My questions are:

1. According to my understanding, the problem arises because the first back-propagate backwards the whole `outputs` and `outputs[1,:].unsqueeze(0)` was released so second back-propagate failed. Am I right?
2. In my case, if I set `retain_graph=True`, will the code run slower and slower according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274929/pytorch-runtimeerror-trying-to-backward-through-the-graph-a-second-time-but)?
3. Is there better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes you are correct. When you already back-propagated through `outputs` the first time (first iteration), the buffers will be freed and it will fail the following time *(next iteration of your loop)*, because then necessary data for this computation have already been removed.
2. Yes, the graph grows bigger and bigger, so it could be slower depending on GPU *(or CPU)* usage and your network. I had used this once and it was much slower, however this depends much on your network architecture. But certainly you will need more memory with `retain_graph=True` than without.
3. Depending on your `outputs` and `labels` shape you should be able to calculate the loss for all your `outputs` and `labels` at once:

   ```
   criterion(outputs, labels)
   ```

   You have to skip the `j`-*loop* then, this would also make your code faster. Maybe you need to reshape (resp. `view`) your data, but this should work fine.

   If you for some reason cannot do that you can manually sum up the loss on a tensor and call `backward` after the loop. This should work fine too, but is slower than the solution above.

   So than your code would look like this:

   ```
   # init loss tensor
   loss = torch.tensor(0.0) # move to GPU if you're using one

   for j in range(4):
       # summing up your loss for every j
       loss += criterion(outputs[j, :].unsqueeze(0), labels[j].unsqueeze(0))
       # ...
   # calling backward on the summed loss - getting gradients
   loss.backward()
   # as you call backward now only once on the outputs
   # you shouldn't get any error and you don't have to use retain_graph=True
   ```

***Edit:***

The accumulation of the losses and calling later backward is completely equivalent, here is a small example with and without accumulating the losses:

First creating some data `data`:

```
# w in this case will represent a very simple model
# I leave out the CE and just use w to map the output to a scalar value
w = torch.nn.Linear(4, 1)
data = [torch.rand(1, 4) for j in range(4)]
```

`data` looks like:

```
[tensor([[0.4593, 0.3410, 0.1009, 0.9787]]),
 tensor([[0.1128, 0.0678, 0.9341, 0.3584]]),
 tensor([[0.7076, 0.9282, 0.0573, 0.6657]]),
 tensor([[0.0960, 0.1055, 0.6877, 0.0406]])]
```

Let's first do like you're doing it, calling backward for every iteration `j` separately:

```
# code for directly applying backward
# zero the weights layer w
w.zero_grad()
for j, inp in enumerate(data):
    # activate grad flag
    inp.requires_grad = True
    # remove / zero previous gradients for inputs
    inp.grad = None
    # apply model (only consists of one layer in our case)
    loss = w(inp)
    # calling backward on every output separately
    loss.backward()
    # print out grad
    print('Input:', inp)
    print('Grad:', inp.grad)
    print()
print('w.weight.grad:', w.weight.grad)
```

Here is the print-out with every input and the respective gradient and gradients for the model resp. layer `w` in our simplified case:

```
Input: tensor([[0.4593, 0.3410, 0.1009, 0.9787]], requires_grad=True)
Grad: tensor([[-0.0999,  0.2665, -0.1506,  0.4214]])

Input: tensor([[0.1128, 0.0678, 0.9341, 0.3584]], requires_grad=True)
Grad: tensor([[-0.0999,  0.2665, -0.1506,  0.4214]])

Input: tensor([[0.7076, 0.9282, 0.0573, 0.6657]], requires_grad=True)
Grad: tensor([[-0.0999,  0.2665, -0.1506,  0.4214]])

Input: tensor([[0.0960, 0.1055, 0.6877, 0.0406]], requires_grad=True)
Grad: tensor([[-0.0999,  0.2665, -0.1506,  0.4214]])

w.weight.grad: tensor([[1.3757, 1.4424, 1.7801, 2.0434]])
```

Now instead of calling backward once for every iteration *j* we accumulate the values and call `backward` on the sum and compare the results:

```
# init tensor for accumulation
loss = torch.tensor(0.0)
# zero layer gradients
w.zero_grad()
for j, inp in enumerate(data):
    # activate grad flag
    inp.requires_grad = True
    # remove / zero previous gradients for inputs
    inp.grad = None
    # apply model (only consists of one layer in our case)
    # accumulating values instead of calling backward
    loss += w(inp).squeeze()
# calling backward on the sum
loss.backward()

# printing out gradients 
for j, inp in enumerate(data):
    print('Input:', inp)
    print('Grad:', inp.grad)
    print()
print('w.grad:', w.weight.grad)
```

Lets take a look at the results:

```
Input: tensor([[0.4593, 0.3410, 0.1009, 0.9787]], requires_grad=True)
Grad: tensor([[-0.0999,  0.2665, -0.1506,  0.4214]])

Input: tensor([[0.1128, 0.0678, 0.9341, 0.3584]], requires_grad=True)
Grad: tensor([[-0.0999,  0.2665, -0.1506,  0.4214]])

Input: tensor([[0.7076, 0.9282, 0.0573, 0.6657]], requires_grad=True)
Grad: tensor([[-0.0999,  0.2665, -0.1506,  0.4214]])

Input: tensor([[0.0960, 0.1055, 0.6877, 0.0406]], requires_grad=True)
Grad: tensor([[-0.0999,  0.2665, -0.1506,  0.4214]])

w.grad: tensor([[1.3757, 1.4424, 1.7801, 2.0434]])
```

When comparing the results we can see that both are the same. 
This is a very simple example, but nevertheless we can see that calling `backward()` on every single tensor and summing up tensors and then calling `backward()` is equivalent in terms of the resulting gradients for both inputs and weights.

When you use CE for all *j* 's at once as described in ***3.*** you can use the flag `reduction='sum'` to archive the same behaviour like above with summing up the CE values, default is ‘mean’, which probably leads to slightly different results.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and excellent reply. But in my case, I don't need loss at all, I only care about gradients. So do I have the only solution `retain_graph=True`?

Comment: Did you try what I've written at ***3.***? This should still apply for you, regardless what you do later after calling `backward` on the `loss`-tensor.

Comment: Sincerely apologize for the confusion, would you please have a look at the example that I edited now?

Comment: @Tengerye I wonder why you wan't to create gradients w.r.t. your input data? But still I don't see why you can't call `backward` once for every iteration *i* like I described in ***3.***. Did you try? If so, why didn't it work?

Comment: I clarified my question again. Sorry for the late reply. I am studying about attacking deep learning models so I care about the gradients w.r.t. the input data instead of weights. Your kind reply does remind me of back-warding only once and I am still working on it. Sincerely thank you again. @blue-phoenox

Comment: I am not sure if the loss is still correct when I try to backward on the loss of a specific `j`.

Comment: @Tengerye I made an edit, there you can see that it is equivalent.